# Вывод на экран объекта arraylist C#

Tags: c#

Как вывести на экран объект класса `arrayList`? Пробовал `foreach`, но он не работает с объектами.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Zoo newZoo = new Zoo("NSK");
        Cell oneCell = new Cell(5, 60, 10, 1);
        Cell twoCell = new Cell(10, 80, 20, 2);
        Animal oneAnimal = new Animal("Тигр",true);
        Animal twoAnimal = new Animal("Лев", true);
        Animal threeAnimal = new Animal("Пантера", true);
        newZoo.addCell(oneCell);
        newZoo.addCell(twoCell);
        oneCell.addAimal(oneAnimal);
        oneCell.addAimal(twoAnimal);
        twoCell.addAimal(threeAnimal);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < oneCell.getAnimal().Count;i++)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: переопределить метод ToString(), базового класса System.Object, и в цикле вызывать его. или обращаться на прямую к полям объекта - Console.WriteLine($"{oneCell[i].Property1} {oneCell[i].Preperty2}");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (Animal o in oneCell.getAnimal())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.getName());            
        }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант решения номер 1**. Переопределение `ToString()` базового класса System.Object

```
public sealed class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public bool IsAlive { get; }

    public Animal(string name, bool isAlive)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsAlive = isAlive;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} isAlive : {IsAlive}";
    }
}
```

применение :

```
        var animalList = new List<Animal>();

        foreach (var animal in animalList)
        {
             //можно вызывать явно ToString() или пропустить явный вызов, пример будет показан ниже 
             Console.WriteLine(animal.ToString());
        }
```

еще можно так :

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(", ", animalList));
```

или так :

```
    animalList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

**Вариант решения номер 2**. Перебор массива и интерполяция строки, обращение к свойствам объекта.

```
        var animalList = new List<Animal>();

        foreach (var animal in animalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{animal.Name} isAlive : {animal.IsAlive}");
        }
```

еще можно так:

```
        animalList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Name} isAlive : {x.IsAlive}"));
```

Полезные ссылки :
[MSDN System.Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netcore-3.1)
[MSDN Свойства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/properties)
[MSDN String interpolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)